# Listview disable certain check box once checked

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox

Please help me with this!
I have a `ListView` with checkboxes enabled. I need to disable all the checked items checkboxes, where the user should not try to click it again.
Here is my code, where I am getting error.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Try
        ' submit
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\jtb43661\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\IGI Event Tracker\IGI Event Tracker\bin\Debug\Logs\Event.LOG"
        If Not File.Exists(path) Then
            Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(path)
            End Using
        End If
        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(path)
            For Each item In ListView1.CheckedItems
                sw.WriteLine(item.Text & "->" & " Completed-@---> " & Label2.Text)
                item.SubItems.Add("Completed")
                item.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
                'If item.subItems.text = "Completed" Then
                'here I need to disable or lock the checked checkboxes 

                'End If
            Next
            sw.Close()
        End Using
        MsgBox("Events Submitted Successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your implied logic correctly, once a `ListviewItem` is checked and contains a `ListViewSubItem` with the Text property equal to "Completed" you do not want the user to be able to uncheck that item.  The addition of the "Completed" subitem is performed in a Button click event handler something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems
        ' add "Completed" subitem only if it does not currently exist
        Dim hasCompleted As Boolean = False
        For Each subitem As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In itm.SubItems
            hasCompleted = subitem.Text.Equals("Completed")
            If hasCompleted Then Exit For
        Next
        If Not hasCompleted Then itm.SubItems.Add("Completed")
    Next
End Sub
```

As far as I know, there is no way to directly disable a `ListViewItem` to prevent it from being unchecked.  However, the `ListView` does have the `ItemCheck` event that can be used to prevent changing the "Checked" state.  The following code prevents the Checked state change if the item being "UnChecked" has a SubItem with the Text "Completed".

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCheck
    If e.CurrentValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items(e.Index)
        For Each subitem As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
            If subitem.Text.Equals("Completed") Then
                e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue ' do not allow the change
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @tharun If that is the case, consider upvoting the answer.  You have been a member for 3 years but have never voted on a Q or A.  Upvoting posts you find helpful or informative  helps others find good posts.  It is a way to help others if you are not able to post answers.  The brief [tour] explains more.

Comment: Sure Plutonix :)